# Are the Chuunibyou light novels still going?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

A thing that I'd like to know is whether or not the series of light novels for Chuunibyou has ended. Has anyone read the third volume?

Comment: Are you asking for whether an _official_ announcement has been made?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love,_Chunibyo_%26_Other_Delusions#Light_novels) it was March 14th, 2014 that the third volume was released in japan and the [official site](http://www.kyotoanimation.co.jp/books/chuunibyo/books/) only lists 3 volumes while the last news post was on the 27th of March 2014 and google translate doesn't reveal anything about anything happening to the author or a statement that it had been cancled

Comment: I'm asking wether an official announcement was made or the third volume's conclussion was a definitive one (ie. it seems everything is said and done)

Comment: @VicentMartínBonet The LNs are ongoing, with no indication that the series has been canceled. I presume this means that volume 3 does not constitute a definitive ending for the series. But I haven't actually read the LNs, so I don't really know what's in volume 3. (I mean, I could translate the blurb on Japanese Wikipedia, but it doesn't say anything about Yuuta and Rikka getting married and living happily ever after or anything else similarly conclusive.)

Comment: Oh thanks. Guess I'll try and find someone who can read me the translation and see for myself.

Comment: I've been reading some speculations (in Japanese: [1](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10164679560),
 [2](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14146619714)) that the 4th volume might not come out. Basically, they said that there was dispute between the author and the publisher, the differences between the anime, light novel and game might confuse people, and the illustrator for the LN has left the company. This doesn't mean that it *won't* have 4th volume since there's no official statement about it, though. (3 years between 2nd and 3rd vol.)